# Angular - Moving firestore document to another collection problem

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to move a document from one collection to another using AngularFirestore.

Eventually after some time I came up with a working solution:

```
    // Subscribing to original document to get data
    this.afs.collection('boards').doc(this.boardId)
            .collection('categories').doc(this.categoryId)
            .collection('taskList').doc(id)
            .valueChanges().subscribe((task: Task) => {

      // Adding a copy of document into desired category
      this.afs.collection('boards').doc(this.boardId)
              .collection('categories').doc('doneList')
              .collection('taskList').doc(id)
              .set({name: task.name, description: task.description, authorId: task.authorId, creationDate: task.creationDate,
                    lastEditorId: task.lastEditorId, lastEditDate: task.lastEditDate,
                    isApproved: taskApproved, points: task.points, completitorId: this.userId, completitionDate: new Date()});

    });

    // Deleting task in original category
    this.afs.collection('boards').doc(this.boardId)
            .collection('categories').doc(this.categoryId)
            .collection('taskList').doc(id).delete();
```

And it's working, the problem is, when I'm deleting original document, it generates an error:

`"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"`.

I'm pretty sure it's caused by deletion of subscribed document, so I was trying to unsubscribe it in various ways, use `then()` function to handle deletion and some more. Nothing helped so far.

How do I handle it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

When you call subscribe(), it returns a Subscription object, that you should hold on to:

```
subscription = this.afs.collection(...)...snapshotChanges().subscribe();
```

Then you can use that to unsubscribe when you no longer want updates:

```
subscription.unsubscribe()
```

In your subscription listener, you might also just want to guard against undefined `task` values just to be safe.

```
if (task) {
    // only work with task here
}
```

Comment: When subscribing snapshotChanges for a document, I can't use an argument of Task type, so cannot copy document data. "Argument of type '(task: Task) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PartialObserver<Action<DocumentSnapshot<unknown>>>'." I was trying to unsubscribe subscription of valueChanges() but it doesn't work (result: document not copied but deleted).

Comment: But if(task) did the job here haha :) Thank you for your time!

Comment: If the solution worked for up, please accept the answer as correct.